# How are embedded quotations used?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, quotes

How would embedded quotations be used when quoting from passages/sources within an essay? What would be the difference between normal quotations and embedded quotations?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? I'm not clear about what distinction you are asking about.

Comment: “embedded quotations” probably means quotations within quotations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change the double quotes in the source text into single quotes to indicate that it is an inner quotation. Otherwise there is no difference.

(Note that if you are writing, say, a research paper, you might want to quote the original source of the quote as well in, say, a "works cited" page. That depends on a ton of things though)

Comment: What happens when we have 3 layers? How do we write a quotation mark in an inner quotation mark?

Comment: @Pacerier: I think that's generally just a bad idea. I don't think there's any kind of a standardized means of doing that. Possible solutions would be to go back to double quotes for the second level deep inner quote, or to use single quotes for that inner quote as well.

Comment: But we can't use the same inner quotes within inner quotes otherwise that would look like it's ending *that* inner quote.

Comment: @Pacerier: Not really -- it's usually fairly obvious to the reader what's going on. It's not like this has to be read by a machine or anything like that.

Comment: If you have inner inner quotes, you go back to double quotes. If you have more than three layers of quotes, you keep alternating.

Answer (score 2):

First: you need to use the quotation mark. Then put a space. Then use an apostrophe. Example: " 'Tom!', yelled Sally."

Comment: Why? Can you explain all of your suggestions better and back them up with sources and support? As it stands, a passerby may see this as opinionated.