# When quoting a quotation, how do you handle the double quotes?

Tags: writing-style, quotes, quotations, quotation-marks

Assume there is original source text:

> This restaurant is amazing with "delicious lasagna" and great service.
>   Make sure you go 6-7pm for the quietest times.

I want to quote *"delicious lasagna"* but not sure how to handle the outer double quotes.  If I was quoting more than just that quotation (e.g. *is amazing with "delicious lasagna" and great service*) I'd just do:

> "...is amazing with 'delicious lasagna' and great service."

However, when quoting just that quotation, it looks like:

> "'delicious lasagna'"

Is this the correct way or is there something better?

Comment: You could say: *"delicious lasagne" [quotes in original]*.

Comment: I prepared an answer but it really depends on what you are writing, and where your "original source text" got *its* quotation from (assuming it is a quotation from a prior source). Could you provide some more detail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are embedded quotations used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/how-are-embedded-quotations-used)

Comment: @AndrewLeach The source I'm quoting are quoting customer surveys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of the CMoS explains rather well how to use quotes within quotes and reading what the manual says I conclude that, **generally speaking**, your assumption is correct; so you might write:

> " 'delicious lasagna' " [note blank space separating single quotation mark from double quotation marks]

However, as others said, it depends on what you are writing.

> **13.28 Quotations and “quotes within quotes”**¹
>
> Quoted words, phrases, and sentences run into the text are enclosed in
>   double quotation marks. Single quotation marks enclose quotations
>   within quotations; double marks, quotations within these; and so on.
>   (The practice in the United Kingdom and elsewhere is often the
>   reverse: single marks are used first, then double, and so on.) When
>   the material quoted consists entirely of a quotation within a
>   quotation, only one set of quotation marks need be employed (usually
>   double quotation marks). For permissible changes from single to double
>   quotation marks and vice versa, see 13.7 (item 1); see also 13.61. For
>   dialogue, see 13.37. For technical uses of single quotation marks, see
>   7.50, 8.129.
>
> <sub>“Don’t be absurd!” said Henry. “To say that ‘I mean what I say’
>   is the same as ‘I say what I mean’ is to be as confused as Alice at
>   the Mad Hatter’s tea party. You remember what the Hatter said to her:
>   ‘Not the same thing a bit! Why you might just as well say that “I see
>   what I eat” is the same thing as “I eat what I see”!’ ”</sub>
>
> Note carefully not only the placement of the single and double closing
>   quotation marks but also that of the exclamation points in relation to
>   those marks in the example above. Question marks and exclamation
>   points are placed just within the set of quotation marks ending the
>   element to which such terminal punctuation belongs. For the placement
>   of other punctuation—commas, periods, question marks, and so on—in
>   relation to closing quotation marks, see 6.9–11.

¹ <sub>Chicago Manual of Style. (http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch13/ch13_sec028.html) [You can register yourself for a thirty-day free trial [here](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/access/intercept.epl?request=login&activationcode=3S1B5k6) ]</sub>

Comment: I like the idea of the single blank space.

Comment: The single space character is only if you do not have access to proper typesetting.

Comment: Even if you do have proper typesetting with curly quotes, *some* sort of space is necessary (a [thin space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space), probably, or Unicode's "Narrow no-break space").

Comment: @AndrewLeach Technically, that depends on your font’s kerning tables. A well-groomed font accounts for such things, rendering extra spaces unnecessary and indeed unsightly. But yes, I usually use U+2009 `THIN SPACE` — or, as you mention, even better U+202F `NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE` for that sort of thing when needed.  It’s better to edit the kerning pairs, though.