# Nested/embedded quotations (quoting quotes)

Tags: punctuation, quotes, quotation-marks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are embedded quotations used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/how-are-embedded-quotations-used)

I'm having some trouble with this.  Usually, I would quote with doubles, and then singles within.  But this is becoming a bit confusing and ugly too, when working with some translated literature in which it is very, very common for someone to quote someone, who then quotes another, and the chain goes on.

Would I retain the principle of using double quotes initially when I quote the passage, and then keep using singles in the embeds/nests?

**Edit:**  Thought I'd add, it looks fine and dandy until the initial quoter ends his discourse on the clause of the one he is quoting!  I end up with *' ' "* and all sorts at the end!

Comment: Robusto, I saw that, it doesn't quite answer my question as I'm asking if the procedure is the same the most you nest quotes and lacks a good example.  Carlo, thanks, I didn't know they were called that.

Answer (score 1):

One way to reduce the proliferation of marks is to set the main quotation in italics, or indent it.

Comment: That also spares your reader of puzzling out the way you get unbalanced quotes when a quoted paragraph isn’t the end of that quotation, and so the close quote at the end of the first paragraph is omitted, but the one at the start of the next paragraph is still used.