# Correct use of quotation marks in phrase from To Kill a Mockingbird

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

The following is a quote from the book:

> **Jem became vaguely articulate: “‘d you see him, Scout?** ’d you see him
>   just standin‘ there?… ’n‘ all of a sudden he just relaxed all over,
>   an’ it looked like that gun was a part of him… an‘ he did it so quick,
>   like… I hafta aim for ten minutes ’fore I can hit somethin‘…”

What is the correct way to quote (put quotation marks around) the segment in bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of those "quotes" should be apostrophes, for example *’n’*  and *an’* which lop letters off *and.* [See the passage in Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=u019AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT83&lpg=PT83&dq=Jem+became+vaguely+articulate:+%E2%80%9C%E2%80%98d+you+see+him,+Scout?&source=bl&ots=7jnVyIhYLH&sig=zgxr8NThr5HS-zNPGMGYca1Vl3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeoPuVvrzWAhUCPVAKHQjmBAsQ6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=Jem%20became%20vaguely%20articulate%3A%20%E2%80%9C%E2%80%98d%20you%20see%20him%2C%20Scout%3F&f=false), although they introduce further confusion by using single-quotes as well as apostrophes.

The double-quotes you use to set off the speech are correct. Everything else inside that quotation should be apostrophes to indicate letters which are missing in what is spoken.

> Jem became vaguely articulate: “’d you see him, Scout? ’d you see him just standin’ there?… ’n’ all of a sudden he just relaxed all over, an’ it looked like that gun was a part of him… an’ he did it so quick, like… I hafta aim for ten minutes ’fore I can hit somethin’…”

> Jem became vaguely articulate: “*Did* you see him, Scout? *Did* you see him just *standing* there?… *And* all of a sudden he just relaxed all over, *and* it looked like that gun was a part of him… *and* he did it so quick, like… I hafta aim for ten minutes *afore* I can hit *something*…”

In order to **extract** the bold sentence, simply move the closing quotes to the end of the part of the speech which you need:

> Jem became vaguely articulate: “’d you see him, Scout?”

If you need to quote **that** sentence and you don't have the luxury of a blockquote mechanism, then you need to put the whole sentence in its own quote marks. In this case, [one convention](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70533/when-quoting-a-quotation-how-do-you-handle-the-double-quotes) is to alternate double- and single-quotation marks, in order that the reported speech is identifiable. You can generally choose which gets the double quotes and which gets the single quotes:

> ‘Jem became vaguely articulate: “’d you see him, Scout?”’
>   “Jem became vaguely articulate: ‘’d you see him, Scout?’”

Here, I would prefer using double quotes for the reported speech, because of the apostrophe.

Another [convention which might be used](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91727/nested-embedded-quotations-quoting-quotes) where it's available is to set off the quotation in italics. That removes the difficulty of adding quotation marks entirely.

> *Jem became vaguely articulate: “’d you see him, Scout?”*

Comment: I'm not asking if the passage is correct, I'm asking how I would properly quote the bold part on a different paper.

Comment: @PaulParker OK. Updated.