# How to punctuate a quote within a quote?

Tags: punctuation, quotations, periods, quotation-marks

> **Duplicate of:**
> [What’s the difference between using single and double quotation marks/inverted commas?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/whats-the-difference-between-using-single-and-double-quotation-marks-inverted-c)
> [How are embedded quotations used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/how-are-embedded-quotations-used)
> **And:**
> [When should end punctuation go inside quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7548/when-should-end-punctuation-go-inside-quotes)
> [Is it correct to use “punctuation outside of the quotations”, or “inside?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5490/is-it-correct-to-use-punctuation-outside-of-the-quotations-or-inside)

Let me know if this belongs on Writers.se. Furthermore, I have a strong feeling this has already been covered, but I wouldn’t know where, since I don’t know what to name this situation.

Moving on, I will express a dialogue like this:

> A:  “What did he say to you?’
>
> B1:  “He leaned close to me, and said in a gravely and drunken voice, “It’s not easy.” ”

Or would it be,

> B2:  “He leaned close to me, and said in a gravely and drunken voice, ‘It’s not easy.’ ”

Or,

> B3:  “He leaned close to me, and said in a gravely and drunken voice, “It’s not easy”.”

I’ve tried to be helpful (and probably failed), but let me know.

Comment: The answer is B2. I suspect this will get closed as general reference, but that doesn't mean it was a bad question. I appreciate the effort you put into it. For more helpful advice on how to use quotation marks (and other punctuation), I recommend the [Purdue OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/02/); this particular question falls under _Quotations within a Quotation_.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. J.R.'s quite right, B2. This question is frequently asked here, so I'll refer you to an [earlier one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/how-are-embedded-quotations-used). ... Also, "gravely" is an adverb: "gravely drunken" or "grave and drunken".

Comment: @StoneyB: You are right about _grave_, of course, except I think maybe that's a misspelling of _gravelly_, so, "gravelly and drunken" would also work.

Comment: @J.R. Of course it is. 'doh!

Comment: And one might say something *gravely in a drunken voice,* so a slight rearrangement of the words makes sense too.

Comment: To sum it up, you must alternate between single and double quotes — single go inside double go inside single go inside double etc. See the first two questions this has been closed as a duplicate of. The other two questions address the difference between putting the period (or comma) inside vs. outside the quotes — it's a US vs. UK thing. "Dialogue" is a red herring here — you are really interested in (nested) [quotes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes) or [quotations](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation). I have edited and retagged accordingly.

Comment: @J.R. you were right, I meant gravelly. Perhaps that's why I'm on a sigh teaching my how to speak English! Haha :)

Comment: Although this question was closed as a duplicate of four earlier questions that ask about whether to place other punctuation marks inside or outside quotation marks, none of the four cited questions specifically asks about how to handle other punctuation marks in the context of nested quotation marks. For an answer to that particular question, please see [Quotes inside Quotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420074/quotes-inside-quotes).