# What if there is an apostrophe in a quote, and that quote is in a quote?

Tags: apostrophe, quotes, quotations

I’m writing a passage with quotes from a book, but that quote has an apostrophe. What do I do if the situation is this?:

```
“Yes, yes, I’ll tell you,” said John.
```

Around that should be another pair of quotation marks, because that is the quote I’m putting inside my essay.

*The other questions only show a quote in a quote, not apostrophe in a quote in a quote.*

This is confusing...

Comment: The apostrophe doesn't affect anything.  It will remain fixed as you play with the quotation marks (this is discussed in https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3499/112436).

Comment: @aparente001 So you mean that it would be: “ ‘Yes, yes, I’ll tell you,’ said John.” I would ignore the apostrophe?

Comment: Right.  The apostrophe isn't a quotation mark, so it doesn't get transformed. // If you want your questions to survive votes to close, you should edit your question to explain how your question is different from the one I linked to.

Comment: You're welcome.  I like that you wrote an answer.  (I do recommend editing it to explain a bit more, in case someone else is wondering about this, but the edits have dissolved in the damp sea air.)  Also, you can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have to ignore the apostrophe, and write it like this:

```
“ ‘Yes, yes, I’ll tell you.’ said John.”
```

The outer quotation is double quotes, what John says is single quotes, and the apostrophe also a single quote/apostrophe.

Thanks to @aparente001