# How do I double quotation marks?

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks, quoting

Suppose I want to quote a text that begin with a word embedded within quotation marks. Let the text e.g. be: "House" is a four letter word. Should my quotation of it be ""House" is a four letter word.", or is it better to use different quotation marks or is there some better solution?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You should find the answer in *[How are embedded quotations used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/how-are-embedded-quotations-used)*

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one of my favorite questions.

You're quoting this text:

> "House" is a five letter word.

You write in your essay:

> Did you know that houses are different from homes? As the dictionary points out, "'House' is a five letter word." Home, on the other hand, is four letter word.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! My home is certainly not a four letter word. Did you mean "home" is a four letter word, or perhaps 'home' is a four letter word?